# Not receiving messages on Steam?

Tags: steam

When you message someone on Steam, there usually is a tag at the bottom of the window when the last message was received. What does it mean if that doesn't show up? I've messaged a friend who is online, but that tag doesn't appear. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

"Last message received" actually refers to the time that your friend last sent you a message, and has nothing to do with them receiving your message.